# Getting reference to the controls on a custom dialog (Android JUnit tests)

Tags: android, junit

My current mission is to make some Android GUI tests and I am having difficulties with finding a reference to elements that are located on a dialog opened from the base view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new_type);
```

For finding controls, I use findViewById, f.ex:

```
Button addType = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button_add_type);
```

This works well. After pushing this button a custom dialog is opened:

```
new DialogNewType(v.getContext(), controller).show();
```

and finding controls that are on that dialog are making me headache.

I suppose the basic idea would be something along the lines: 
`findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_type).findViewById(R.id.whatever_control_on_the_dialog)`, but the reference to the dialog returns null. I also tried to get the reference to the dialog by using `findViewById(R.layout.my_dialog)`, also returns null.

Alternatively, I tried to reach the controls with Robotium framework, like this:

```
ArrayList<EditText> test = solo.getCurrentViews(EditText.class);
EditText et = test.get(0);
```

In this way, I get the reference to the needed control, however I find it very dirty solution and would prefer to get to the same solution using "plain old Android".

This is how the dialog layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/dialog_new_type"
>

    <EditText 
     android:hint="@string/dialog_new_type_edit_hint"
     android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:visibility="visible"
     android:id="@+id/dialog_new_type_edit">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialog does not extend View, that's why you cannot use:

```
findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_type);
```

Why don't you just use:

```
findViewById(R.id.whatever_control_on_the_dialog)
```

Comment: Ah, so that explains the null for the dialog. Thanks. However, when I search for a EditText as you suggested, it returns null as well. This is what I used: typeName = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_type_edit);

Comment: In layout xml file is this EditText control directly nested in the dialog element (LinearLayout) (I added the snippet in the description).